# Issues faced during npm install

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, npm-install

npm install command results in the following error

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/react-dom/-/react-dom-16.0.11.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.2.4 (sha512-0RNDbSdEokBeEAkgNbxJ+BLwSManFy9TeXz8uW+48j/xhEXv1ePME60olyzw2XzUqUBNAYFeJadIqAgNqIACwg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-30T16_35_20_927Z-debug.log
```

I have tried everything found on issues on Github, like using `npm init` and `npm cache clean --force`

Using a 64-bit architecture.
NVM version 1.1.7
Node Version 11.0.0
NPM Version 6.4.1

Kindly guide me, moreover, I have noticed that I don't have VS build tools 2019, but I have Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm cache clean --force`

This will surely solve the issue.